# How to design buffer using single power supply(without using rail to rail OPAMP)?

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, analog, embedded, power-electronics

I am designing circuit which contains 4 buffers(for overcoming impedance mismatch between two circuits). These buffers needs to work somewhat linear in 0 volt to 5 volt range but the problem is I only have one 24 volt battery source for all circuitry and OPAMP requires dual power supply. How i can overcome this problem in efficient manner without using rail to rail OPAMP?

Comment: Not clear what you are doing. Maybe an emitter follower?

Comment: put a schematic up of the signal sources and sinks, so we don't have to guess

Comment: *"without using rail-to-rail opamp"* Why this restriction? RRIO opamps are not much more expensive (especially since you just need a 0-5V range). And that would allow you to have a very simple design. Every other solution will be bulky and expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a negative supply from the positive supply: -

[image]

[image]

Or, if you don't want to build one buy an isolating switcher from Traco: -

[image]

Comment: Couldn't somebody just show him how to bias up the input and decouple the output?

Comment: @EJP - decoupling the output doesn't work at DC and if the OP has slow moving signals then that would be a problem with your idea.